# HQL как получить случайную запись в таблице

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Имеется таблица в MySQL базе данных. Нужно выбрать одну случайную запись и получить на выходе объект-сущность.

Я пробовал сделать это так:

```
Entity getRandomEntity() {
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(count);
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (Entity) session.createQuery("from Entity where id = :rand")
            .setParameter("rand", rand).getSingleResult();
}
```

Но это не работает, т.к. записи в базе иногда удаляются и, соответственно, id имеют пропуски.

Что тут можно сделать?

Comment: Можно пронумеровать все записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через LIMIT можно ограничить

```
session.createQuery("FROM Entity").setFirstResult(rand).setMaxResults(1)
```

Comment: Действительно, так работает. Ну и при вычислении rand нужно конечно максимальный id использовать, а не количество записей. Спасибо

Comment: @SoulDrake id здесь не при чем, важно кол-во записей в таблице. У вас может быть максимальный id равен миллиону, а записей в базе будет всего 2, если вы сделаете setFirstResult(1000000), то не получите ничего.

Comment: А, блин, точно, это в моем первоначальном варианте надо было макс ид брать, т.к. я там по нему и искал, а тут уже по количеству надо, запутался немного )) Спасибо еще раз

Answer (score 0):

Типа так:

```
session.createQuery("select id from Entity id order by rand()")
  .setMaxResults(1)
  .list()
```